# Change given function parameter within the function c++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, parameters

I wrote an function called swap to swap given two elements within the function. But when I use it in another function, it doesn't work. How to get it work?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void swap(int *a, int * b){
    int temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}

void sum(int x, int y){
    int *a;
    a = &x;
    int *b;
    b=&x;
    swap(a,b);
    //cout << x << endl << y << endl;
}
int main(){
    int a=0, b=1;

    //swap(a,b);
    sum(a,b);
    cout << a << endl << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: two things: first, it's _very_ weird to call a function `sum` which takes two integer but neither returns an integer nor calculates a sum. second: you shouldn't use pointers for that. It's horrible C-style, not C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b=&x;
```

should be

```
b=&y;
```

Also, you are swapping local copies. `sum` should be:

```
void sum(int& x, int& y)
```

Also, this already exists. It's called [`std::iter_swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap).

Answer (score 0):

`x` and `y` are passed by value to `sum` so `swap` is working on a local copy not the actual variables from `main`. You will also need to modify `sum` and your call to swap:

```
void sum(int &x, int &y)
             ^       ^
{
 // other code
 swap(&x,&y);
      ^  ^
}
```

If you leave you call to `swap` like this:

```
swap(x,y);
```

you will actually call `std::swap`. I am going to assume you will be adding more code to `sum` otherwise the name is not consistent with what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You probem not in swap, but in sum function, you pass x an y by value and modify and swap copyies of values later to fix this you need to change `void sum(int x, int y){` to `void sum(int& x, int& y){` this will leads to x and y being passed by reference so that sum will be able to update them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess by 'wrong' you mean the output of the last cout doesn't show 'a' and 'b' as you'd expect. But you're passing them to 'sum' by value.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are just learning about pointers and references.

Your function `swap` swaps the contents of two pointers. Note that you have put in `using namespace std` and std also has a swap function so I would suggest removing that from your source, albeit yours will be a closer match if you pass in pointers to ints.

Your function called `sum` is a clear misnomer as it doesn't actually sum or add anything, it tries to do a swap by calling the pointer version.

To fix your particular bug, it would have to take its parametesr by reference, and `b` should point to y, not x.